# How to read \n as part of text if it is stored in CSV format

Tags: python-3.x, list, csv, newline

I've set `delimiter="|"` and `newline="\n"` but when I read a text the \n in the text does not give me a new line on printing. For example:

`"Good Morning \nHow are you?"|"Its been a while since we met."`

When I take the objects as elements of a list through `csv.reader`

```
with open ('file.csv', 'r', newline="\n") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
    List = []
    for lines in r:
        List.append(lines)
```

The `List` would look like this

`["Good Morning \nHow are you?","Its been a while since we met."]`

and if I run the code

```
for i in list:
    print i
```

The expected output of the elements would be

```
Good Morning
How are you?
Its been a while since we met.
```

but what I end up getting is

```
Good Morning \nHow are you?
Its been a while since we met.
```

Whereas if I directly assigned `List=["Good Morning \nHow are you?","Its been a while since we met."]`
I do not get this problem. Is there any workaround to this?

I need to use both CSV and \n in the text.

Comment: `/n` is not ``\n``. These may be typos or they may be the actual problem; make sure to fix them anyway so we're all talking about the same thing.

Comment: Check if inside your CSV is there literally "Good Morning /nHow are you?". I don't think so.

Comment: @Jeroen, really sorry for the typo... I have fixed it in my post. My csv file had a large amount of lines and words so I had to make up a simpler scenario of it... Yes the csv file contains \n and it was originally stored in a list but I made it into a csv file. It was working how I wanted in the list form but not once I used the csv. I found that many were facing similar problems with csv but I didn't find a way to fix it in Python.